# python xml parsing error due to charater &

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

I wrote below code. And some of my xml files have a special characters start with & and end of ;
I would like to ignore special characters to do parse some xml.
I need to parse xml with the "`tree = elemTree.parse(content)"` because I already made my code so bulk. After then I need to ignore that kind of character.

could you give me a tip?

```
        with open(filename, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as content:
        # content를 파싱하여 tree형태로 저장한다
        tree = elemTree.parse(content)
```

Comment: can you post the xml and the exception with stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code can solve this problem.
Some characters like ' can be ignored.

```
with open(filename, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as content: # just adding errors='ignore'
```